# Use 2 optocouplers?

Tags: opto-isolator

What is the advantage of using two feedback optocouplers? 
I'm not sure why this single voltage power supply would use 2.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Wild guess - they're using a pair of unipolar opto's as a bipolar opto.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I cannot follow the lines, but is it not possible the optocouplers are for two different signals? It's quite commmon (needed) to have multiple signals going through their own optocoupler.

Comment: any guess on what those two signals might be? Maybe voltage and current?

Comment: A signal itself is not either voltage or current, it's a combination of these that makes it a signal. The signals can be anything (I'm not so much intro electronics that I know each part of a voltage power supply to be honest). However, I am doing a MIDI project and each MIDI in signal has its own optocoupler. Also optocouplers are used for isolating the high voltage (110V/220V) part from the low voltage (3.3/5V) to make sure those low voltage parts are protected against the high voltage parts (like in a relay for example).

Comment: Maybe this links helps (didn't read it myself): https://www.vishay.com/docs/80065/80065.pdf

 But according to the link below it seems they are used for preventing shocks.

Comment: Yeah I knew that already. You can get a proportional voltage signal from current via shunt resistor and opamp.